# Cover and aim penalty for an overwatch shot triggered from enemy action

Tags: xcom-2

In X-COM 2, it's been reported that on overwatch shots, there is a 70% (when moving) or 60% (when dashing) penalty to aim, but the enemy no longer has cover to make up for it.  When using an ability that allows overwatch to trigger on enemy actions, not just movement, what is the penalty?  Do they still have their cover, in which case you might as well just shoot at them?  Do they not have cover and have a 70% aim modifier, as if they had moved?

Comment: I think the aim penalty for dashing targets is actually 49%

Comment: @Dragonrage Any source for that?  All the questions here, based on the configuration files, point to a .6 multiplier.

Comment: I was reading something about it in one of the wikis. It may be wrong though. Let me see if I can find the link.

Comment: http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Overwatch

Comment: @Dragonrage Do you have any references for xcom 2?

Comment: I can't tell you for certain, but remember that an overwatch shot will only be taken on the step **after** the enemy is in range. One can use this to their advantage by running to a corner of a building - out of sight of the enemy - and shooting the enemy in the head by peaking around that corner. The "overwatch on enemy action" would trigger when the shot is to be fired, where "regular overwatch" will not fire a shot.

Answer (score 3):

> When using an ability that allows overwatch to trigger on enemy actions, not just movement, what is the penalty?

The overwatch aim penalty gets applied to all overwatch shots*. This includes normal overwatches and covering fire.
The explanation for this is that it is a *reaction* shot; a *quick reaction* by the soldier who fires his gun; therefore his aim is reduced as opposed to an "aimed" shot (normal shut during your turn). The aim penalty is therefore tied to the soldier taking the shot and is independent of what the soldier is shooting at (other aim buffs/debuffs can still have a stacking effect, of course).

But when an enemy takes a shot as opposed to running away; they will still have their cover because they never moved away from it.
**Even if** an enemy is behind full cover and side steps before taking a shot; the full cover will still be in effect. The side step itself is not considered movement and will not trigger an overwatch, but the **shot** (that caused the side step) will still trigger Covering Fire.

This does mean that Covering Fire reaction shots have a worse chance to hit than a normal overwatch shot. For this reason, you should only give CF to your soldiers with above average aim (and who have other reaction shot bonuses); or else you'll just be wasting bullets most of the time.

---

*Technically, it gets applied to all *reaction* shots. This includes overwatch shots, reaction shots that occur when a suppressed enemy makes a move, the Return Fire pistol shots, and other "automatic reaction shots" (e.g. the Close Quarters Combat perk in XCOM EW. It exists in XCOM2 too but I'm not sure if it has the same name).